# Socket IO check if in the same page

Tags: javascript, laravel, socket.io

I got a question. I'm new to socket.io and currently, I'm building a project that includes the Chatting functionality.
The socket went well, the user can send the message and it will be saved into the database.

HOWEVER. I encountered a bug, the scenario is like

User A sends a message to User B.
Then, User A sends a message again to User B.
BUT, User B is currently viewing User C message.
It appended on the page that showing messages between user B and user A, in User C page.

My client side- show.blade.php

```
<script>
    let ip_address = '127.0.0.1';
    let socket_port = '3000';
    let socket = io(ip_address + ':' + socket_port);

    var receiver_id = "{{ $friendInfo->id }}";
    var my_id = "{{ Auth()->id() }}";

    $(document).ready(function() {
      initiateChat();
      scrollToBottomFunc();
      $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
      });

      const sendMessageForm = $('form#message_form');
      // to send the message by submit
      $('#submitButton').click((e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        sendMessageForm.submit()
      })
      const socketSendMessage = ({
        message
      }) => {
        socket.emit('send_message', {
          receiver_id,
          message
        })
      }

      sendMessageForm.submit(e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const messageContainer = $(e.target.message)
        var message = messageContainer.val()
        var datastr = "receiver_id=" + receiver_id + "&message=" + message;
        if (message != '' && receiver_id != '') {
          messageContainer.val('');
          //go to send message to store in DB
          sendMessage(datastr);
          socketSendMessage({
            message
          })
          appendMessage(message)
        }
      })
      //Append message into <div> with ID of #context
      const appendMessage = (message, sender = true) => {
        $('#context').append
        (`
          <ul class="no-bullet">
              <li class="clearfix">
                  {{-- if message from id is equal to auth id then it is sent by logged in user --}}
                <div class="speech-bubble ${sender ? 'speech-left bg-highlight' :'speech-right color-black'} " >
                      ${message}
                      <br>
                    <small>{{ date('h:i a', strtotime($message->created_at)) }}</small>
                </div>
              </li>
          </ul>
        `)
      }

      socket.on('receive_message', (message) => {
        appendMessage(message, false)
      })
    })

    function sendMessage(datastr) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/message',
        data: datastr,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status, err) {},
        complete: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          scrollToBottomFunc();
        }
      })
    }

    function scrollToBottomFunc() {
      $('#context').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#context').get(0).scrollHeight
      }, 0);
    }

    socket.on('connected', msg => {
      console.log({
        msg
      })
    })

    function initiateChat() {
      socket.emit('connect_chat', {
        user_id: my_id,
        receiver: receiver_id,
      });
    }

  </script>
```

Server-side

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const server = require('http').createServer(app);

const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*'
  }
});


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('connect_chat', (data) => {
    socket.join(data.user_id);
    io.in(data.user_id).emit('connected', {
      'message': 'connected'
    })
  })

  socket.on('send_message', (data) => {
    io.in(data.receiver_id).emit('receive_message', data.message)
  })

  console.log('connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', (socket) => {
    console.log('disconnected');
  });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server is running');
});
```

The interface examples are as shown below:

[Sending From User A to User B. No problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlyJD.png)

[**Bug** User A send to User B. But it appears on the user C page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAQxv.png)

I'm stuck and need some help. THANK YOU!

Comment: Send the sender_id along with the receiver_id in the `socketSendMessage` function and in the receiving side cross-check if the current window is the one that corresponds to the sender. Keep in mind the JS code will be running in all open chat windows. Not too experiences with websockets so wouldn't know the specifics though

Comment: ahhhhhhh. I see the problem now. I found it. I've included the `receiver id` and `my_id` inside the socketSendMessage whenever emit. Thank you!